# POST запрос Angular2

Tags: angular2

Каков общий принцип запросов к серверу в Angular2?

Я так понял, что get запрос только на получение, а post только на запись. Чтобы нам сделать запись в базу и потом скачать это на клиента, нужно сделать и post и get запросы? Только post запрос нам ничего не возвращает, получается (как в стандартном XMLHTTPrequest)? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для записи можно использовать и POST и GET. Отличие в том что параметры в первом случае передаются в теле запроса во втором в адресной строке. Ответ от сервера вы получите в теле Respons объекта. Но принято POST использовать для передачи данных на сервер.

Comment: Если мне нужно послать данные на сервер, и чтобы он обратно, в зависимости от полученных данных, вернул новые, в ангуляре2 нужен только post? Просто я обращался к серверу постом, данные перезаписывались, но обратно ничего не возвращалось. И в туториалах по ангулару и get и post запросы использовали.

Comment: Это вопрос к бэкенду, что будет возвращаться.

Comment: @user287120, почитайте про REST

Comment: Я могу post запросом только получить данные с сервера, ничего туда не записывая?

Comment: Можете и только получить. Здесь вопрос к серверу и его точек доступа.

Answer (score 1):

Вы немного запутались. И `GET` и `POST`, могут возвращать значения. Однако различия всё же есть. В тело запроса `POST` можно поместить данные, например в виде `multipart/form-data`, что позволяет передать бинарные данные или группу данных, например несколько `JSON` в удобном виде, ответы же могут прийти в разных видах.

В `GET`, параметры указываются только в формате `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, т.е. передаются в строке запроса, подбоным образом:

```
http://example.com?param1=1&param2=sdf
```

Теоретически всегда можно было бы пользоваться одним методом, но их разграничение даёт возможность обращаться по одной и той же ссылке для разных целей.

Также не стоит забывать, что архитектура `REST`, предоставляет методы `PUT` и `DELETE`, а ещё предоставляются запросы по параметром в пути `/shop/1/item/2`, где 1 является `id` магазина, а 2 `id` товара в магазине 1.